# Xamarin.Forms - Tooltip as menu

Tags: xamarin.forms

I couldn't find it anywhere, so I'm trying this option.

I have an app with frames and when I click on the frame I want a tooltip-like window to come up where the user can select an option. Something like this:

[image]

[image]

I took a look at Xamarin.Android.Tooltips, but that doesn't seem to be able to handle multiple options to choose from. Are there other packages available which work better for this case?

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this.

**1.[Xamarin Community Toolkit PopUp](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Xamarin-Community-Toolkit-Platform-Perfect-Popups-Part-1).**

There is a sample included in above link,you can check it here: https://github.com/ahoefling/XCT-Popups-Samples?WT.mc_id=xamarin-c9-jamont .

The main code is:

```
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // uncomment the different types of popups
        HelloPopup();

         //PositionPopup();
         await ReturnValuePopup();
         await GenericTypePopup();
    }

    void HelloPopup() => Navigation.ShowPopup(new HelloPopup());
    void PositionPopup() => Navigation.ShowPopup(new PositionPopup());
    async Task ReturnValuePopup()
    {
        object result = await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(new ReturnValuePopup());
        await DisplayAlert("Popup Response", $"{result}", "OK");
    }

    async Task GenericTypePopup()
    {
        var result = await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(new GenericValuePopup());
        await DisplayAlert(result.Title, result.Message, result.Ok);
    }
```

**2.[Display Pop-ups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups)**

To display an action sheet, `await` [DisplayActionSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displayactionsheet?view=xamarin-forms) in any Page, passing the message and button labels as strings. The method returns the string label of the button that was clicked by the user.

A simple example is shown here:

```
    private async  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string action = await DisplayActionSheet("Choose an option", "Cancel", "Delete", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3");
        Debug.WriteLine("Action: " + action);
    }
```

**3.nuget [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)** .

It is a cross platform plugin for Xamarin.Forms which allows you to open Xamarin.Forms pages as a popup that can be shared across iOS, Android, UWP, and macOS. Also the plugin allows you to use very simple and flexible animations for showing popup pages.

For more , check: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this does not exist in vanilla Xamarin.Forms unless you're ready to create your own custom view and platform renderers. You may consider using a NuGet package like [ACR User Dialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) which provides many pre-programmed views that would probably satisfy your requirements.